# Configuring Flexible Hierarchical Structure in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tinkerpop3

I am trying to integrate the [Apache Tinkerpop gremlin-driver](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) library into my Spring Boot application. This library requires serialiser configuration to be passed as a `Map<String, Object>` parameter which is expected to conform to a JSON/YAML-like structure.

In order to allow the application user to configure the driver at runtime, I tried to use Spring Boot's `ConfigrationProperties` annotation to load the Gremlin configuration and initialise the library.

Unfortunately, Spring loads the nested lists in the serialiser configuration as `Map<String, Object>` with the key representing the index, instead of a List.

```
Expected: {
  "ioRegistries": [
    "org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry"
  ], 
  "serializeResultToString": true
}

Actual: {
  "ioRegistries": {
    "0": "org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry"
  }, 
  "serializeResultToString": true
}
```

**application.yml**

```
gremlin:
  endpoint: localhost
  port: 8182
  username:
  password:
  sslEnabled: false
  serializer: GRYO_V1D0
  serializerConfig:
    ioRegistries:
      - org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry
    serializeResultToString: true
```

**GremlinApplication.java**

```java
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.Serializers;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(GremlinConfiguration.class)
@Slf4j
public class GremlinApplication {

  private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Autowired
  private GremlinConfiguration config;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GremlinApplication.class, args);
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void setup() throws JsonProcessingException {
    log.info("Serializer Config: {}", mapper.writeValueAsString(config.getSerializerConfig()));
    // Prints 'Serializer Config: {"ioRegistries":{"0":"org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry"},"serializeResultToString":true}'

    MessageSerializer serializer = Serializers.valueOf(config.getSerializer()).simpleInstance();

    // Expects config to be map representing JSON structure, throws exception.
    // Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
    serializer.configure(config.getSerializerConfig(), null);

    Cluster.build(config.getEndpoint())
        .serializer(serializer)
        .credentials(config.getUsername(), config.getPassword())
        .port(config.getPort())
        .enableSsl(config.getSslEnabled())
        .create();
  }

}
```

**GremlinConfiguration.java**

```java
import java.util.Map;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties("gremlin")
public class GremlinConfiguration {

  private String endpoint;
  private Integer port;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private Boolean sslEnabled;
  private String serializer;
  private Map<String, Object> serializerConfig;

}
```

Is there a way to configure Spring Boot to convert these nested Maps into Lists without explicitly defining every possible configuration option?

Or even to deserialise the configuration property to a Jackson JsonNode (or equivalent) that can then be converted to the required data structure?

Comment: Can you show your desired output? It seems like you're saying you want a `Map<String, Object>` for the library but you have a `Map<String, Object>`...

Comment: @chrylis Apologies, I've edited the question to be clearer